# Python matplotlib Y axis labels multiplied by scalar

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot an image from numpy.array. Y axe-labels are linear but I need the values multiplied by a number. In this example Y labels should go from 0 to 4000, so multiplied by 2.

[image]

Any ideas?

My code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure('Nav Panel')
fig.set_size_inches(12, 12)
imgplot = plt.imshow(nupyarray,interpolation='bicubic')
imgplot.set_cmap('Greys_r')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: The best way is to add the `extent`, e.g. `plt.imshow(..., extent=[0, 1000, 0, 4000])`. That  way also the coordinates shown in the status bar will be consistent. Possibly you will also want to change the aspect ratio, e.g. `plt.imshow(..., aspect='auto')`

Comment: Perfect !, Thanks.